# Sorting by Time the posts from 2 or more different sources

Tags: java, android, date, gridview, comparator

i'm developing an app for android in java.

I'm getting 1,2,3 or more sources from websites that have posts.

You can think like i'm getting 3 different rss feeds and adding them into one page.
The problem is i want to add them to the gridview with correct time arrangement.
i mean if posts created at like below
 22/08/2014 12:00  - first post first source
 22/08/2014 12:05 - first post third source
 22/08/2014 9:00 - first post second source.
.
.
.

The arrangement should be (the newest post should be at top)

-second source first post
-first source first post
-third source first post
and more should be sorted like that.
.
.
.

```
         public static class SortFeedByDate implements Comparator<DoFeed_Item> {


            @Override
            public int compare(DoFeed_Item lhs, DoFeed_Item rhs) {


                if (lhs.getTimePosted() != null || rhs.getTimePosted() != null)
                {
                Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                c1.setTime(lhs.getTimePosted());
                c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                Date t1 = c1.getTime();
                c1.setTime(rhs.getTimePosted());
                c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                Date t2 = c1.getTime();

                if(t2.compareTo(t2) != 0)
                    return t2.compareTo(t1)*-1;
                else{
                    c1.setTime(lhs.getTimePosted());
                    c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
                    c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
                    c1.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);
                    t1 = c1.getTime();
                    c1.setTime(rhs.getTimePosted());
                    c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
                    c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
                    c1.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);
                    t2 = c1.getTime();
                    return t2.compareTo(t1);

            }
                }
                return 0;

             }
         }
```

this is my class i'm using for comparing items by time

DoFeed_Item is my post item. i'm getting posts from sources and i'm adding required parts to DoFeed_Item and i'm adding every DoFeed_Item to an array and then adaptor of listview..

DoFeed_Item is like in example below

```
new DoFeed_Item(String postTitle,Date postCreated,String urlOfArticle)
```

Different sources sends different time tables.

If it sends time stamp 
i'm converting time like this

```
Date date = new Date(createdAt*1000);
```

if sends with specific time date format

i'm converting time to date like this

The part yyyy-MM-dd or other stuff changes for specific rss feeds.

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");  

                        Date date = null;
                        try {
                            date = format.parse(createdTime);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            Log.e("DoDate","Date parse error : "+ e);

                        }
```

and i'm adding them with correct time arrangement like below :

```
 Collections.sort(FeedItemList, new SortFeedByDate());

 //feed is gridview                         
feed.setAdapter(new NewsAdaptor(mLauncher, FeedItemList));
```

and problem is, everything is placing to gridview like random.....
Times and dates doesn't work as expected.

am i missing something?? like gmt time stuff or something else..

or is comparator wrong?

if you need more about codes or anything else just let me know. I will provide required things.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by comparing t2 with itself in following line:     if(t2.compareTo(t2) != 0).

Comment: @VaibhavRaj hmm probably i did mistake there.i'll check and fix it and let you know whether if it solves my problem or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than converting to a Calendar, assuming you parsed the date correctly you can simply do this:

```
@Override
public int compare(DoFeed_Item lhs, DoFeed_Item rhs) 
{
    return lhs.getTimePosted().compareTo(rhs.getTimePosted());
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29